# Using Ajax GET to download compressed JSON files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

**Background.**

I'm tasked with debugging some `PHP` and `JavaScript` code designed to pull static, `gzip`'ed JSON files from the host server, and manipulate the resulting JSON object's parameters.

Apologies in advance for my misuse of terminology. I have some experience with software development, but very little with web/server development (and almost none with `PHP`/`JavaScript`).

---

**Code.**

To "pull" the `.json.gz` file from the host server, jQuery's Ajax function is used:

```
function myJsonReader() {
    var myJsonFileUrl = getUrl();
    
    function doFunStuffWithJsonFile(jsonObject) {
        // Fun things happen
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: myJsonFileUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json", 
        success: doFunStuffWithJsonFile,
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            console.log("Exception " + exception);
             alert('Failure:', exception);
             
        }
    }); 

}
```

Server-side, we have an `index.php` file, the first few lines of which are:

```
<?php
  header('Accept-Encoding: gzip');
  header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
?>

<html>
<head>
... some HTML code
```

---

The Ajax `GET` request fails. I know the file exists, and I'm passing the absolute path. Moreover, I'm able to read the compressed file if I use `dataType: "text"`, but that, of course, returns "garbage":

```
����%^��0��jN�L/��8�?@��x���351�g��+��~���ׯ���/߿�7���^��di9�y;jY��6�$K�=��4��QTMB�^or��M�P��̡�*}��G�t��K!#�8�Z@[d�9�#����R��N�����y��Պ�������;9�T����B+��VM�#��.:�<ĩ�F�PZ��Ȕl[K̔N[� GȡĚ�.5;P6�H��jeͮ��<�e""�h�-!�>��S�E��Q�m�H�.ڌSAyc�S�MsFHF�K]�H)/ry`�6.��&��-ME���s�����GA��@�rJ�.����)��kR�Vi�6��h�K-`��������
```

If I check the XHR response using:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
```

I also [get garbage](https://pastebin.com/69b0uP9J).

The file is a valid JSON file, readable by Vim with it's built-in `gunzip` capabilities. Moreover, this code was previously able to read these gzipped JSON files without issue using an Ajax call and without the use of external libraries, until some unknown change is presumed to have been made (being messy and mostly undocumented, it hasn't been possible to track down that change).

It is not possible to simply unzip all files we wish to read with this function, nor is it possible to make use of external libraries (e.g. `zlib`), unfortunately.

---

Several sources suggest this is should be relatively straight-forward (e.g. [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858583/how-to-have-a-browser-gunzip-an-ajax-fetched-gziped-text-file), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768047/loading-gzip-json-file-using-ajax)). Sadly, it isn't clear to me what I'm missing.

---

**Edit.**

After re-loading the page, I check the `Network` tab in Chrome's Inspector. I see the `Fetch/XHR` request for my JSON file. The headers for which include the following:

```
Requested Method: GET
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Which, to my untrained eye, seems to be properly configured for accepting compressed files.

Comment: So you are trying to read the file in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I then perform various operations on the JSON file's attributes in JavaScript (e.g. operations on `jsonObject.attributeName`). Still reading through the rest of the code to determine the scope of what is done with these, but I'll need to access the attribute values in JS.

Comment: Having `header('Accept-Encoding: gzip');` in your `index.php` seems strange, since I thought the [Accept-Encoding header was for clients to specify what encoding they can understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding). Anyway, did you try adding `headers : {'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip'},` to your AJAX request, as suggested in the answers you referenced? What was the result?

Comment: @kmoser I agree that having `header('Accept-Encoding: gzip')` in `index.php` seems odd, although this is well outside of my wheelhouse. I did try adding `headers : {'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip' },` to the AJAX request.  I'm met with the error `Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32525490/14073182) seems to suggest that one should *not* specify this in the AJAX request, and instead specify `Content-Encoding: gzip` in `index.php` (which is already done).

Comment: _"this code was previously able to read these gzipped JSON files without issue using an Ajax call "_ It sounds like something may have changed on the web server itself. What server software are you running (Apache, Nginx, etc.) and was it recently upgraded?

Comment: @kmoser It looks like we're on Apache/2.4.6, which was last built a few months ago (I believe this issue cropped up later, but could be wrong). I have no familiarity with server software, unfortunately. What steps could I take to see if this is a server issue?

Comment: @10GeV You could try downgrading Apache, preferably in test environment. Compare the HTTP headers in the current Apache to those of the downgraded Apache to see what changed.

Comment: I think you need to configure your server response by setting the the MIME type,  header('Content-type: application/json');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server returns this header for the AJAX call:

```
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

without this one:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

then the browser will **not** uncompress the response. For it to transparently uncompress it, you need
something like this instead:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Adding `Accept-Encoding` or `Content-Encoding` headers to your HTML page (as you did) has of course
no effect. You should remove them.

The headers sent by Apache depend on the way it is configured. Your server configuration may have been changed recently.

You have 2 solutions:

- Modify your Apache configuration so that it sends the expected headers for `.json.gz` files
- Use a PHP script to retrieve your compressed JSON files

Here is an example of such a script (`getJSON.php`):

```php
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
readfile("path/to/$name.json.gz");
?>
```

The URL to retrieve `test.json.gz` would be:

```javascript
url: 'getJSON.php?name=test'
```

Remark: as stated in a comment, a recommended practice is to check the value of `$name` (e.g. allow only letters and numbers) to forbid
the use of `../` characters, which would allow an attacker to access `.json.gz` files outside of the intended directory.

**UPDATE**

You said in a comment that the following `.htaccess` file was present in the directory that contains the JSON files:

```
<filesMatch ".(gz)$">
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
    </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

The directive should send the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header for `.gz` files. However, `.htaccess` files may not
be processed by Apache, depending on the value of the [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
directive. If `AllowOverride` is set to `None` (and [`AllowOverrideList`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist)
is also `None`, which is the case by default), then `.htaccess` files are ignored.

Note the default value for `AllowOverride`:

> **Default**: AllowOverride None (2.3.9 and later), AllowOverride All (2.3.8 and earlier)

It means that, as of Apache 2.3.9, `AllowOverride` is set to `None` by default.

You said in a comment that you upgraded to version 2.4.6 recently. If `AllowOverride` is not explictly set in
your Apache configuration, then it explains why your `.htaccess` file has no effect anymore.

A solution is to add this in your Apache configuration file:

```
<Directory /path/to/your/json/files/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Your example of `getJSON.php` is obviously just a proof-of-concept but when implemented for real it should be updated to [sanitize user input](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250132/sanitizing-user-form-input-in-php).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the `PHP` script a try. I'm not terribly familiar with server software... how would one configure Apache to provide the appropriate headers (or, alternatively, what can I search for to find the appropriate documentation... I can't seem to find anything by Googling/searching the docs)?

Comment: The `.htaccess` in the relevant directory has ```<filesMatch ".(gz)$">
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Encoding "gzip"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: @kmoser It's always better to sanitize, but in this case, even without sanitizing, all you can do is steal `.json.gz` files on the server, which is not very useful.

Comment: @10GeV I think I figured it out. See my update.

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following code in your ajax return code:

```
  let blob = res.data;
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = 'Your File Name';
    a.href = e.target.result;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid it isn't clear to me how this works, nor what exactly is meant by the Ajax "return code" (I assume you mean function called in case of an error, as the "success" function is never called?). Could you clarify?